# Ace editor: Why is the keyboard event handler being called twice?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Currently, I am capturing keyboard events whenever any key is pressed in my ace editor, via this javascript code:

```
editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler({
    handleKeyboard: function(data, hash, keyString, keyCode, event) {
        console.log(ketString)
        ...
    }
```

The problem is that the handler function is being called **twice** every time a key is pressed in the ace editor, but I want it to be called once. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Based on feedback from @Michael Geary, I added a console.trace() every time the keyboard handler is called, and I have traced the calls from two locations in the ace.js code:

```
this.onCommandKey = function(e, t, n) {
    var i = r.keyCodeToString(n);
    this.$callKeyboardHandlers(t, i, n, e)      <-----------
}
,
this.onTextInput = function(e) {
    this.$callKeyboardHandlers(-1, e)           <-----------
}
```

The question, why are `onCommandKey` and `onTextInput` both being triggered?

Comment: Are you running this initialization code twice? What does a breakpoint or `console.log` before this code show?

Comment: @MichaelGeary Good idea! But unfortunately, that wasn't the case. I just tried console.log right before this piece of code, and it's called only once.

Comment: Aw rats. Well isn't that how debugging always goes? ;-) Here's another idea for you. First, make sure you're using a non-minified development version of Ace and any other JavaScript libraries. Now add a `console.trace()` call inside `handleKeyboard`. This will print a stack trace when the function is called - or in your case _two_ stack traces when you hit a key. The question then will be whether these traces are identical or show two different places where the call originated. If nothing jumps out at you, paste the traces into the question and someone may have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are calling it with different hashid and often with different keystring. The first call is for the keypress event where hashid is the combination of modifier keys as seen in https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/55f206452dd2ebd4094edbae7a145bfb09da87bb/lib/ace/keyboard/hash_handler.js#L225.
And the second is for textinput event with `hashid=-1`

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. But why is the keyboard handler being called twice with different `hashid`s?

Comment: because it handles both kerpess and input events.